# JSON Parse using C#

Tags: json, api

Anybody has any idea how to parse below type of JSON object where same object named objects are present in master object. Below is an example

abc{
"abc":"123"
}

How to parse the child abc value?

Answer (score 0):

You can use [Json.NET](http://json.codeplex.com/) it is vary easy to use. Json.NET handles JSON arrays natively, and will parse them into any type, string,int etc.

Answer (score 0):

Are you currently using a JSON framework? Maybe check out Json.NET: http://www.newtonsoft.com/json.

Then you could do something like:

```
int onetwothree = jObject.SelectToken("abc.abc");
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use http://www.newtonsoft.com/json to parse any json string on c#:
Your example :

```
 var jsonString= "{\"abc\":{ \"abc\":\"123\" }}";
 var jObj = JObject.Parse(jsonString);
 var abcValue = jObj.SelectToken("abc.abc").Value<string>();
```